# How can I write a CMakeList.txt file for heavily nested project?

Tags: c++, cmake

Suppose my source code has the following directory structure:

```
C:\USERS\PC\SOURCE\REPOS\my_app_src
├───apps {a.hh, b.cc, c.hh, d.cc}
│   └───biosimulations {main1.hh, main1.cc, x.hh, y.cc}
└───core {w.cc, x.hh, y.hh, z.cc}
    └───algorithms {p.hh, p.cc, q.hh, r.cc, s.hh, s.cc}
        └───trees {r.hh, r.cc, main2.hh, main2.cc}
```

Each folder has any number of header and source files with any name.

How can I write a `CMakeList.txt` file for this project?

This is scientific software.

I need to be able to use various parts of the same library to compile and build executables for multiple applications.

For example, in the above sample, `main1.exe` and `main2.exe` are supposed to be two different executable files.

Sometimes, I need to be able to switch off one or another executable from compiling.

> *Do you want the project to support testing, installation, and/or packaging?*

No, I don't need them. I just need to be able to compile and execute the apps.

> What is in core?

Model classes. e.g., Atom, Protein, Chain, etc.

> Are the source files for `core` part of a single library or executable?

Part of executable. There is no static or dynamic library in the project.

Comment: *"Sometimes, I need to be able to switch off one or another executable from compiling."* Probably you just need to learn about the `--target` option for `cmake --build`. It doesn't do exactly what you're asking for but instead builds a single target including all of the dependencies that are out of date. If you need to build multiple sets of targets without specifying all of them via `--target` option, you could use `add_custom_target` in combination with `add_dependencies` to create additional targets that build the targets listed as dependencies.

Comment: You could of course conditionally exclude targets from your project too using the `if` command and a cache variable, but with the first suggestion you avoid unnecessary cmake reconfigurations...

Answer (score 2):

Using add_subdirectory and add_library commands, recursively add all of the source files in the directory structure.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.x)
project(my_app)

# Add subdirectories recursively
add_subdirectory(apps)
add_subdirectory(core)
add_subdirectory(simulations)
add_subdirectory(ui)
add_subdirectory(utils)

# Create the final executable
add_executable(my_app main.cpp)

# Link the libraries to the executable
target_link_libraries(my_app core simulations apps ui utils)
```

Then in each subdirectories(apps,core,simulations,ui, utils) you would need to add a new CMakeLists.txt that tells which source files are in that directory and create a library.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.x)

SET(SRC_FILES 
    program.cpp
    )

#for static libraries
add_library(core STATIC ${SRC_FILES})

#for dynamically linking libraries
add_library(core SHARED ${SRC_FILES})

# If you need executable here
# add_executable(core ${SRC_FILES})
```

This needs to be repeated for all subdirectories, untill all sources are covered. Above examples gives general structure, you need to define CMAKE flags as required.

Comment: One more thing to know: my main.CPP file is in app-> biosimulations>main.CPP.  how do I write that in cmake file?

Comment: you just add it to the CMakeLists.txt in that directory